# $stmt - call_user_func_array expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having these problems no matter how much I tried to fix them.
I'm working on an HTML Visual Editor CMS and every time I log in these errors show up.

Here are the errors:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
Call to a member function execute() on boolean
```

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,"bind_param") ,$this->refValues($param_arr));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is clear.  You should learn to read error messages, process them, and act on the error message.

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
> Call to a member function execute() on boolean

The first part of the error *call_user_func_array()* tells you exactly where to find the error.  Given your code, it can only be on the line indicated below (although error messages **also include** line numbers, so using the line number would be useful as well):

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

// this is the only "call_user_func_array" in your code, so must be the issue
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,"bind_param"), $this->refValues($param_arr));
```

The next part of the error - *first array member is not a valid class name or object. Call to a member function execute() on boolean* tells you that specifically, the `array( $stmt, "bind_param" )` is not a valid function, because `$stmt` is boolean.

The reason that's throwing is because although you check if `$stmt` is set, you don't actually prevent continuing operation if it is *not set*.

A very simple solution would be to set the proper reporting mode for mysqli, by adding the following lone before mysqli connect:

```
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

once it's done, it will kill the two birds with one stone: it will stop the code execution and will inform you, what was the problem with prepare()

Comment: Be sure to check my very last sentence: the true issue is with `$query` not being valid.  I would encourage you to figure out why / how that is happening, and prevent _that_